# MUI - styles by makeStyles are damaged after update MUI and React versions

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, material-ui, makestyles

Using `MUI Dropdown` inside `components library`.

running the library inside `Storybook` it works fine.

consume the component in a different `React` project, the design is damaged.

Dropdown label has `top: 60px`, it shouldn't, Menu Item on hover have wrong `background color`, Menu has extra `padding-bottom` and more.

Inspecting (for example: the Label) it has this `makeStyles class`:

```
.makeStyles-root-12 {
    top: 60px;
}
```

this bad behavior is happening after update MUI version in the components library:

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.6.1",
    "@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^5.6.0",
```

and updating the project (consuming the library) `React version` to 17:

```
    "react": "^17",
    "react-dom": "^17",
```

make things weirded, there is a flow of events that make the styles right again:

go to different tab -> return to first tab (where `Dropdowns` at) -> styles are as should be

make things even more weird: the same project on a different computer don't experience this issue.

**Dropdown's Label from the components library**

```
const useLabelStyles = makeStyles<
  {},
  { disabled: LazyBoolean; hasTooltip: LazyBoolean; readOnly?: boolean }
>({
  root: {
    fontSize: '14px !important',
    lineHeight: '20px !important',
    color: ({ disabled, readOnly }) =>
      disabled || readOnly
        ? 'var(--neutral-element-50) !important'
        : 'var(--neutral-element) !important',
    marginRight: ({ hasTooltip }) => (hasTooltip ? '10px !important' : ''),
    fontFamily: 'Open Sans !important',
  },
});

const labelClasses = useLabelStyles({
    disabled,
    readOnly,
    hasTooltip: Boolean(tooltipText),
  });

<InputLabel
  data-testid={generateDropdownTestIdWithSuffix(TEST_ID_SUFFIX.LABEL)}
  classes={labelClasses}
>
  {label}
</InputLabel>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had another component that used a different version of MUI. Each component in my project has its npm package. Because of that, I had a clash between the versions. IT WAS FIXED once I updated all the components to use the newer MUI version.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour could be related to:

> @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore, deprecated in v5. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.

> @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

You can check more about it [here](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/).

Also, the Mui documentation has a guide about migration from v4 to v5, and a specific section related to styles [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/migration-v4/#1-use-styled-or-sx-api).

So, basically you should go from `@mui/styles` to `@mui/material`

Comment: did that :( thats why it works on the library app. i just don't understand why it's not working on the consuming project

Comment: Maybe it's worth changing one simple component from `makestyles` to `styled()` just to check if the same behaviour persists.

Comment: good point, will try

Comment: Another day i did a code sample to test something and with `makeStyles` i had to insert an `! important` to style get effect. You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-style-components-vs-makestyles-oriwrs?file=/src/MakeStyles_Example.jsx)

Comment: thx for the response but my issue is that the whole mui css isn't working right. important might help if it was one thing but there is too much.

Comment: @ItayTur, have you found out what was the issue?

Comment: @SirghiMihail The issue was that I had another component that used a different version of MUI. Each component in my project has it's own npm package. Because of that I had a clash between the versions. Once I updated all the components to use the newer MUI version it was fixed.

Comment: @ItayTur, had the exact same cause of an issue and fixed it as well. Thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem today when using mui versions 5.15.14 in a React Storybook project and consuming them in a different next js project. Nexx.js project used 5.15.10. When both were updated to the 5.15.14 version issue was fixed.